# Question about JIRA connector on SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, jira

I have a team site specific to our team and I want to display my JIRA board of current sprint on home page of our team site.

Is it possible to implement? If Yes, please suggest me the best approach to do this.